# Powershell script to copy list of files from csv and log failure/success

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to log success/failure of a file copy from a list of files in csv. I have it check for the directory and create it if it is not there. Some of the files in the csv file do not exist and I'm trying to capture at least the failures. One file copies in testing but I don't get anything in the failed log file for the ones that do not. I can't figure out what I'm missing, any help would be appreciated.

```
Import-Csv -Path c:\scripts\file.csv  | foreach {
    if (-not (Test-Path -Path $_.Destination))
    {
        # Create directory if needed
        mkdir -Path $_.Destination 
    }
    # Copy file
    Try
    {
    Copy-Item -Path $_.Source -Destination $_.Destination -verbose 
    }
    Catch {Write-Output $_.Source | out-file -append -FilePath "c:\scripts\failed.log"}
}
```

Comment: You're missing `-ErrorAction Stop` most likely

Comment: At the end of the Copy-Item line? I tried that and I have the same results.

Comment: `$_` inside of the `catch { }` block is referencing the current `$error` object. Either swap the *psitem* variable to something else first, or use the `-ErrorVariable` parameter in `Copy-Item` for an alt solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find the reference, but doing `foreach ($variable in $collection)` is apparently more performant than the method you're using. It also has the advantage that you're not confusing your `$_` in the `foreach` block with the new one that will get created on error in the catch block.

Try separating it out for clarity and see what happens:

```
$copyfiles = Import-Csv -Path c:\scripts\file.csv  
Foreach ($f in $copyfiles) {
    if (-not (Test-Path -Path $f.Destination))
    {
        # Create directory if needed
        mkdir -Path $f.Destination 
    }
    # Copy file
    Try
    {
        Copy-Item -Path $f.Source -Destination $f.Destination -ea Stop 
    }
    Catch {
        Write-Output $f.Source | out-file -append -FilePath "c:\scripts\failed.log"
        # if you want to see the error message thrown after "-ea stop", uncomment below
        # write-host "$_"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I ended up splitting my script into multiple parts to grab what I needed. I did test the above, thanks for helping me learn!